# Vagrant reset my VM and now I am frightened I lost my work

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I have a horrible situation and I hope you can help.

This morning, the terminal opened in my VM hanged, I tried to access Virtualbox and it went unresponsive. I killed Virtualbox manually and typed `vagrant up`. Vagrant (`vagrant ssh`) booted on a VM that pretty much seems the default one and I am terrified that all my work has been lost.

Typing `vmboxmanage list vms` shows:

`wasp_1375609265" {29663113-786b-4b8a-adc8-2edecf06bcff}`

which is the same UUID I find on the `.vagrant` file.

I am on a Mac OSX Montain Lion, the version of vagrant I am using is `1.0.6` and Virtualbox is `4.2.16`.

**Is there any way I can access the image at the previous state it had before I manually killed it?** I can't believe that vagrant or Virtualbox purposely overwrote the image with a default one

Answer (score 5):

It turned out that I am an idiot and the image was not lost. For some reasons Virtualbox saved it with a cryptic name and vagrant reverted to the default vagrant box `wasp_32...` when I run it again. I found the image I was looking for simply running all the `*.vmdk` I found under `~/VirtualBox VMs`.

After that I followed the instructions I found [here](http://robinwinslow.co.uk/2012/10/05/what-to-do-if-your-vagrant-vm-crashes) to make vagrant booting the correct image

Comment: The link PO shared is pretty useful.

Comment: Same issue hapened to me yesterday, the link you gave saved my day. Thank you.

Comment: Experienced same, link was helpful, in contradiction of step 3 there I needed to update update id file under virtual box directory( `.vagrant/machines/<machine_name/default>/virtualbox/id`) and I am using vagrant 1.8.1